# Refreshing XAML items without using Refresh() method

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, refresh

I'm using C # WPF.

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to update the XAML elements without having to use the `Refresh()` method that you see in the following code.

Now I am encasing the codes related to the C# `doPlay()` method that is launched inside the MainWindow through a thread and the XAML code.

Can anyone suggest a way to update progress bars without having to use the `Refresh()` method?

```
   private void doPlay()
    {

        Transfers.Add(new Transfer(Utils.RandomString(6), Utils.RandomString(6), Transfer.Type_t.download, "Red"));
        Transfers.Add(new Transfer(Utils.RandomString(6), Utils.RandomString(6), Transfer.Type_t.download, "Blue"));
        Transfers.Add(new Transfer(Utils.RandomString(6), Utils.RandomString(6), Transfer.Type_t.download, "Yellow"));
        Transfers.Add(new Transfer(Utils.RandomString(6), Utils.RandomString(6), Transfer.Type_t.download, "Cyan"));
        Transfers.Add(new Transfer(Utils.RandomString(6), Utils.RandomString(6), Transfer.Type_t.download, "Black"));
        Transfers.Add(new Transfer(Utils.RandomString(6), Utils.RandomString(6), Transfer.Type_t.download, "Brown"));

        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
        {
            TransfersXAML.ItemsSource = Transfers;
        }));

        Random rnd = new Random();

        for (var i = 0; i < 100 * Transfers.Count; i++)
        {
            var next = rnd.Next(0, Transfers.Count);
            mre.WaitOne();
            int index =  next;

            if (Transfers[index].CurrentStep < 100)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                Transfers[index].CurrentStep++;

                Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
                {
                    TransfersXAML.Items.Refresh();
                }));

            }
            else i--;
        }
     }
```

The XAML relative code:

```
        <UniformGrid x:Name="DownLeftPanel" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2">
            <ListBox x:Name="TransfersXAML" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Transfers}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ProgressBar Height="30" Minimum="0" Maximum="{Binding NSteps}"
                                     Value="{Binding CurrentStep}" Foreground="{Binding Color}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <ListBox.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Get info" Click="GetTransferInfoClick" />
                        <MenuItem Header="Cancel" Click="CancelTransferClick" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </ListBox.ContextMenu>
            </ListBox>
        </UniformGrid>
```

I tried to simply remove the Action from BeginInvoke, but in this way the bars are no longer displayed, that is, removing these instructions from the first posted code:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
{
     TransfersXAML.Items.Refresh();
}));
```

---

This question is related to the following one: [Network threads blocking the GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49939633/network-threads-blocking-the-gui?noredirect=1#comment86896412_49939633), in particular, referring to the comments below the question itself.

Comment: So you are trying to update the CurrentStep property or why do you need to refresh? Does the Transfer class implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Answer (score 0):

If the `Transfers` class implements the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of the `CurrentStep` property, you could simply set this property on the background thread without ever calling the `Refresh()` method:

```
for (var i = 0; i< 100 * Transfers.Count; i++)
{
    var next = rnd.Next(0, Transfers.Count);
    mre.WaitOne();
    int index = next;

    if (Transfers[index].CurrentStep < 100)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        Transfers[index].CurrentStep++;
    }
    else i--;
}
```

Comment: @kitsune: Did you try to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface or what happened?